# How to override component styles within Mui5 theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm in the process of upgrading from Mui4 to 5.

After upgrading, my index file looks like that (note I'm using JSS, hence the StyledEngineProvider):

```
function renderApp() {
  ReactDOM.render(
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Typography variant="h2" component="h2">H2 TEST</Typography>
          ...
        </ThemeProvider>
      </StyledEngineProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
  );
}
```

And my theme:

```
createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTypography: {
      defaultProps: {
        title: 'test h2 title',
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontSize: '10px',
          fontWeight: 500,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I can see my theme been is used as the "title" attribute is added to my Typography component. But everything within styleOverrides seems to be dropped.
Also, colors added to theme.palette works, but theme.typography.h2 doesn't change any style either. I have the same logic for other components and it doesn't seems to work.

As specified in [Styles broken after migrating to v5](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#styles-broken-after-migrating-to-v5) I made sure StyledEngineProvider is at the top of the components tree and removed any trace of @material-ui/core (Mui4) from the application.

Comment: Put your object inside `components` property: `{ components: { MuiTypography: {...} } }`

Comment: My bad I didn't copy it properly to SO, I will edit my question. Thanks

Comment: Not reproducible in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customstyles-material-demo-forked-n6txn?file=/demo.tsx). Can you add your import code?

Comment: oh! thanks to your codesanbox I understood that some packages were missing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following the [migration doc](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#update-mui-version), it wasn't clear that the following packages are mandatory even though you use JSS within your application and not emotion. Note that there is no warning whatsoever, for example emotion styles within the theme configuration will simply not be compiled.

You must install the following:

```
npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```